# PrimeFaces Wizard disable/enable custom back/next button?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PF5.3 Wizard component in my page and using custom Next/Back button i am able to disable/enable these buttons by below code

```
<p:wizard style="border:0" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="terminationWizard" flowListener="#{equipTemplateBean.flowListener}"
                        onback="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 0) { PF('stepBackward').disable(); } PF('stepForward').enable();"
                        onnext="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 1) { PF('stepForward').disable(); } PF('stepBackward').enable();">
```

my question is that how to hide/she these button i tried below code

```
onback="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 0) { PF('stepBackward').hideBackNav(); } PF('stepForward').showBackNav();"
onnext="if (PF('terminationWizard').getStepIndex(PF('terminationWizard').currentStep) === 1) { PF('stepForward').hideNextNav(); } PF('stepBackward').showNextNav();"
```

but it is not working .
How to use `showNextNav()`,`hideNextNav()`,`showBackNav()`,`hideBackNav()` methods to hide/she custom buttons?

CommandButton code

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="stepBackward"   value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-w" iconPos="right" onclick="PF('terminationWizard').back()" update="submitButton"/>
<p:commandButton value="Next" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" iconPos="left"
onclick="PF('terminationWizard').next();" widgetVar="stepForward" update="submitButton"/>
```

Comment: But its a custom button and not default back/next button how this code will work with these custom buttons? If you will check for disable/enable i used `widgetVar` of commandbuttons

Comment: Added commandbutton code

Comment: Learn basic html, basic css and learn how to add remove classes by javascript/jquery to show hide things. This is TOTALLY not wizard related. It only makes the question blurry/noisy

Comment: Can you try PF('stepBackward').hide(); instead of PF('stepBackward').hideBackNav(); PF('stepForward').hide(); instead of PF('stepForward').hideNextNav(); and same thing for show too? If you Javscript debuggin on firebug or some browser too enable it and see if you see errors.

Comment: Sorry @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Its not working. After adding this Next/back button stop working